# Detect a form submit in jQuery when it has been dynamically added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, forms

**Scenario:**

I have a select box with it's data populated by data from a php config file. If there isn't a matching value in the select to choose from, I am allowing the user to add a field to it. I have created a small one input form which is added via jQuery and I want to catch the post submission to then defer it to an ajax function.

**Problem:**

As the form is dynamically added I am unable to catch the form submission and the page ends up reloading.

This doesn't work:

```
$('form[name="add"]').on('submit', function(e) {.....
```

**One solution:**

If I don't use a form element and simulate it in a div I can get around by using

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.add_form a[name="submit"]', function() {.....
```

**However:**

Although the solution above works I would appreciate if 1) someone could educate me if it is possible to catch a submission from a form that has been dynamically added to the page using jQuery, and 2) if it would be 'good practice' to use that method

**Update**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="add"]', function(e){ 
    console.log('here')
    e.preventDefault() 
})
```

This event delegation is **NOT** catching the form as I can see from the console with preserve log enabled

Answer (score 7):

Binding dynamically added elements to events can be done using the following. See what [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.add_form a[name="submit"]', function(){
    //your code
})
```

Same principle applies to dynamically added forms. 
Change the event to `submit` and use a selector which will be valid for the dynamically added forms too.

```
$(document).on('submit', '[selector-for-your-form]', function(){
    //your code
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and this does work, however, I made a mistake in my question which I have now corrected. I am wanting find out if it is possible to actually catch it as a form.

Comment: This does work! I can see the form is catching in the console but the page still reloads. e.preventDefault() doesn't seem to take effect. See my edit

Comment: @MartinCurrah any error in console, before it redirects? try to check that with prevent log.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. The jQuery doesn't catch the form submission. Preserve log revealed this

Comment: @MartinCurrah Well I am not able to figure what is happening, may be it has something to do with html.